# React Router v4 global no match to nested route childs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nested-routes, react-router-v4, no-match

How can I redirect the user to a NoMatch component when I have nested routes in React Router V4?

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
injectTapEventPlugin();

import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route,
    Switch
}
from 'react-router-dom';
import Website from './website/Website';

const Register = ({ match}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Route exact path={match.url} render={() => {return <h1>Register</h1>} } />
            <Route path={`${match.url}/detail`} render={()=>{return <h1>Register Detail</h1>}} />
        </div>
    )
}

const App = () => (
    <Router>
        <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" render={() =>  {return <h1>Home</h1> }} />
                <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
                <Route component={() => {return <h1>Not found!</h1>}} />
        </Switch>
    </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

As You can see, there is a NoMatch route below Register but I don't want to use the same Route mapping on my child component Register. In this way, if I go to /register/unregisteredmatch the page just show blank because do not enter in NoMatch Route.

How can I map a global NoMatch without specify that on my child route? I don't want to pass this responsability to the child components.

Thanks.

Comment: you will need to create HoC, register will always render no matter if it has a matched child route inside or none. so you will need to create a handler for that

Comment: @ReiDien If I understood, what I need to make is create an "abstract" component encapsuling the NoMatch handler... Am I right? Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with *Switch* since the following will always render my *NoMatch* component if I do not go to /a

```
<Router history={history}>
  <Switch>
    <Route path='/a' component={A} />
    <Switch>
      <Route path='/b' component={B} />
      <Route path='/b/:id' component={C} />
    </Switch>
    <Route path="*" component={NoMatch}/>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

However, it will work, as expected, if you move your *NoMatch* inside the nested *Switch* like this:

```
<Router history={history}>
  <Switch>
    <Route path='/a' component={A} />
    <Switch>
      <Route path='/b' component={B} />
      <Route path='/b/:id' component={C} />
      <Route path="*" component={NoMatch}/>  
    </Switch>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Even if this is a 'solution' to the problem it is not what you want since the second *Switch* is in a different file like the first *Route* is as well.

So as the application grows and more routes come into play in different files you never know where you need to put the *NoMatch* route for it to work as expected.

Did you find any other solution to this problem?

Comment: Hi! I think that the best approach to this  tois use a High Order Component to handle the not found match as @ReiDien explained in the comment above. I didn't tried yet.

Comment: I found that nested Switch is not supported. So, having routes configured in different files you should not return a Switch from those. What I did was return an array of routes holding the /b and /b/:id routes.

Answer (score -1):

What you could do is define all possibly allowed routes in your root App. Therefore, adapt your App component using optional pattern as follows:

```
const App = () => (
    <Router>
        <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" render={() =>  {return <h1>Home</h1> }} />
                <Route path="/register/(detail)?" exact component={Register} />
                <Route component={() => {return <h1>Not found!</h1>}} />
        </Switch>
    </Router>
);
```

Comment: Thank you @Javaguru! I'm trying to decouple my components without specify in a main file. Just for dynamic import purposes and because that I dont want to map my routes in a main file. I know that I can create a route file according the imports but I searching a way to do that on my modules.