# How to get all param in React Router v4

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to get dynamic routes from the API. When URL has parameter I send them accross API request and fetch the type and according to that type I am rendering my view.

I want to get the whole param from URL. The URL can be any and have any number of params.

Example URL: http://localhost:3000/type/article

App.js

```
<Route path="/:view" component={LayoutPage} />
```

LayoutPage

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.doLoadView(this.props.match.params);
  }
  doLoadView(url) {
    this.setState({ url: url});
    console.log(url, 'match.params.view');
    this.props.actionLoad(url);
  }
```

On match.params.view it's giving 'type'. I know because I defined /:view in app.js so the output is only first param. but I want complete param i.e. 'type/article'.

Comment: Check this answer, I suppose it will provide you with info on what you expect https://stackoverflow.com/a/52752990/5928186

Comment: If you need just to get "pathname" why u need to use react params at all and not just `window.location.pathname` ?

Comment: @Maielo That's a way out but I want to know if there is any way in react router

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm correct but, why not pass another param if you need two params? (/:view/:whatever)

Comment: @Bhawna did the answer solve your problem? if you are still having issues we can look into it. Let us know!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React router doesn't work that way. You set up a route with the params that you need and then 'this.props.match.params' gets all the params for you.

If you set a route like this:

```
<Route path="/:view" component={LayoutPage} />
```

You are only defining one param, so even if you call:

```
http://localhost:3000/type/article/myotherparam/andanotherparam/etc/etc2
```

You will only get `type` because the Route is only expecting the first param (defined as :view).

If you want to define multiple params you do:

```
<Route path="/:view/:param2/:param3" component={LayoutPage} />
```

This way you make sure you have 3 params for example.

**Regex and handling unknown number of params**

Now, since I suppose you don't know how many params are there going to be, you can use a regular expression to match all the params but you will need some parsing afterwards.

So, you can define your route as:

```
<Route path="/:view+" component={LayoutPage} />
```

Call it like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/type/article/myotherparam/andanotherparam/etc/etc2
```

and then if you log:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props.match.params));
```

You will get:

```
{"view":"type/article/myotherparam/andanotherparam/etc/etc2"}
```

You can then split by `/`:

```
this.props.match.params.view.split('/')
```

And you will get the array of params:

```
["type","article","myotherparam","andanotherparam","etc","etc2"]
```

Comment: Thanks @c-havez by using + in path is solving the problem and we can use this.props.match.params.view to get the value