# React-router, optional url parameter with namspace

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am trying to define a react-router  with an optional url parameter prefixed with a namespace. This is an example of such a path:

`path="authors/:authorId/posts/:postId?"
// application.com/authors/8/posts/4`

I want the postId variable part to be optional, but this should include the whole `/posts/:postId` part to be optional. Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Router with optional path parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35604617/react-router-with-optional-path-parameter)

Comment: Not a full duplicate, my question is about the optional fixed path part (which I refer to as namespace).

Comment: Have you tried `path="authors/:authorId?/posts/:postId?"` ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this is a thing that some developers want (haven't seen a good use case scenario where you would need to structure your URL as such),  but the simplest solution is to instead just use a query.

`http://www.example.com/authors/author?authorId=8&postId=4`

Nonetheless, while the answer provided below is specific to the question, the set up for your desired URL structure is the same (see second approach in the answer): [React Router v4 Nested match params not accessible at root level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52684017/react-router-v4-nested-match-params-not-accessible-at-root-level/52684565#52684565)