# How to create a dynamic subheader based on route change or params in React Router v6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In React Router v6, I'm trying to create a dynamic **SubHeader** component that changes based on a particular route or route param. For context, here's a contrived setup:

```
export const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Header>
        <TopHeader />
        <DynamicSubHeader /> // <-- here
      </Header>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="products" element={<Products />} />
        <Route path='product/:id/*' element={<ProductDetail />} >
          <Route path="price" element={<ProductDetailPrice />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

I'd like to update `<DynamicSubHeader />` with different content when navigating between `/products`, `/products/:id` and even `/products/:id/price`

Inside `<DynamicSubHeader />`, I've tried to use the **useParam** hook provided by `react-router-dom`, but it just returns null or the data doesn't persist. It seems you can only use **useParam** when it's nested inside the `<Routes>` component.

I've also tried using the **useLocation** hook to listen for route change and manually setting state there, but it doesn't persist either.

For the time being, I've treated `<Header />` as a *Layout*-component that I've placed in each route. Am I using React Router wrong? Otherwise, any suggestions on how to approach this?

Comment: Check this post. It will help you achieve what you want to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52684017/react-router-v4-nested-match-params-not-accessible-at-root-level/52752990#52752990

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Unfortunately, the post is referring to v4, which does not carry over the same API to v6. There is, however, a useMatch hook that I'm trying to play around with.

Comment: Yes, but the logic still remains the same. You cannot get a match value in the component that actually is at a level up than the actuall nested matched Route

Answer (score 1):

To access your URL data try to use the `match` object with `this.props.match` inside your `<DynamicSubHeader />` component.

This is how it looks on a sample edit route:

```js
//$> console.log(this.props.match)
{
  isExact: true
  params:
    id: "5tkd6w"
    __proto__: Object
  path: "/streams/edit/:id"
  url: "/streams/edit/5tkd6w"
  __proto__: Object
}
```

Once you've got the id you can perform almost any operation and by getting the full URL you can determine other parts of your subheader content.